# webpack-dev-server path publicpath configuration when index.html is in different folders

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I have tried to solve this using path, publicpath, contentBased but no luck.  (only working if bundle.js and index.html are in same folder)

Env:  Webpack 5 + webpack-dev-server + react.

**Issue:**  unable to load application properly in wp dev server, either it show contents folders or not hot reload.
This working fine if generate html & bundle in same folder, but for some reason, I have to keep them in different folders.

**Folder structure**

```
dist\bundle.js
dist\style.css
public\index.html   (generated by HTML-webpack-plugin)
public\....         (other files)
```

**webpack config**

```
output: {
   path: path.resolve(..., 'dist')     //also tried to generate dist inside public
   filename: bundle.js
   //publicPath: path.resolve(..., 'dist') //etc
}
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.resolve(..., 'public')
}
```

I have tried multiple combination with no luck,
I want to keep single version of html file and *avoid modify src manually for dev builds*.

Could someone please guide with right configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contentBase` accepts an array, like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    // ...
    contentBase: [
      path.join(RootPath, 'public'),
      path.join(RootPath, 'dist')
    ]
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

One important thing to note is that `output.publicPath` also plays a crucial role here.

By default (given your `target` is `web` (default) or `webWorker`), [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath) is set to `'auto'`, which means that it determines the `url` to fetch chunks based on how you  require `bundle.js`. That'll work fine in most cases.

However, if your `bundle.js` itself is retrieved using an obscure relative path (e.g. the OP retrieves it from `../dist/bundle.js`), then `'auto'` will not work, and you probably want to set `output.publicPath` manually, using an absolute path (as the OP also ended up doing).

Comment: Thank for quick response, great to know contentBase can watch multiple directory simultaneously.
it should work, but somehow **dist content update still not reflecting**, i am only seeing initial index.html with just loading bar all the time, and it not getting change (replace by react code) when bundle completes.
I am proving public, dist and also tried  to append './' at end.

I  add './' because in log it showing 3 files, which give me impression serving bundle from root.
`asset bundle.js`
`asset  style.css`
`asset ..\public\index.html`
`entry point style.css      bundle.js`

Comment: Ahh.  it getting http 404 on bundle files.  injected script line `src=../dist/bundle.js`
while bundle is available at root of server `localhose:port/bundle.js`
something to do with publicpath

Comment: `publicPath: '/dist/'` in addition to @Domi solution fix it completely

Comment: @user1360135 I updated my answer to explain the phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks for help.
 I used publicPath of devServer instead of output.publicPath to make sure no impact on actual build.